# Bootstrap tooltip title not showing MVc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, tooltip

I have a bootstrap tooltip on a table, as you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

In the view this is the code that I use:

```
foreach (var tecDoc in vehicles.TecDocs)
 {    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title=@(tecDoc.Text + " " + tecDoc.Value)>Hover over me</a>          }   
     <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="HoorayHoorayHoorayHooray!">Hover over me</a>
```

The first tooltip only shows the text: Cod, although it contains the data correctly, because I checked in debug, and it is ok.

[image]

I thought that the problem is that the tooltip text is too long,  but I put the second tooltip with a longer text, and that is showing ok. Do you have any idea what can cause the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is in the title section. I think the issue is the fact that it's lacking quotation marks around it.

basically, you need to make sure that

```
@(tecDoc.Text + " " + tecDoc.Value) = "Some text"
```

Right click it on Chrome and press "inspect element" to see what that currently looks like.

Also I suggest adding a data placement tag. Just to be sure it will look the same everywhere :)

Would have just commented instead of answering, but SO wont let me.. Good luck! :)

Comment: I managed to solve the problem like this: <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title= "@(tecDoc.Text + ":" + tecDoc.Value)">. Thanks for the tip!